# GTK applications look ugly in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: kde, plasma, plasma-5, kde5, window-decoration

I'm using Kubuntu 19.10, with KDE plasma 5 desktop.

I have problems when I run GTK apps, because they like ugly. Here is an example:

[image]

I used the same Desktop in other computer and they look fine.

How could I solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: @DKBose : I have plasmashell 5.18.1

Comment: @DKBose : I install it via ppa `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu eoan main` . I use several GTK apps like FreeFileSync, for example, and it looks ugly too.

Comment: Only Firefox, but it looks ok

Comment: Looks okay for me, also on 5.18.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLStL.png

Comment: Open `System Settings > Application Style` and below all the default KDE themes, you should see `Configure GNOME/GTK Application Style ...` Click on that and then make sure you choose a decent GTK2 theme in the next window.... **Not Raleigh**!!! I don't know why that is included.

Comment: Oh, that's the solution! You can post it to everyone and I'll vote you up! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

KDE Plasma 5.18 has moved things about a bit.

If a GTK application doesn't look proper, please open `System Settings > Application Style` and then, near the bottom, click on `Configure GNOME/GTK Application Style ...`. In the window that opens, choose a suitable GTK2/GTK3 theme but preferably not `Raleigh`. You'll see an approximate preview of your choice as well.

[image: Shutter on Kubuntu 19.10 with Plasma 5.18.1]

Comment: i changed theme from Breeze to Adwaita and then back to Breeze and it looks similar to KDE interface now. Seems like some kind of configuration issue.