# GTK2 theme broken after X/Plasma crash

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, themes, gtk, gtk-2

Today my Kubuntu 20.04 Plasma desktop crashed. Probably the X server crashed, because I was suddenly brought back to the sddm login screen, just like I had pressed Ctrl+Alt+Backspace (but I did not).

I then reboot the system and now my GTK2 applications look ugly. It seems like the Kubuntu theme is no longer applied to them.

Is it a known issue? How to fix it?

By the way, I couldn't find the GTK2/3 theme settings any more in my System settings, which was present in Applications Style configuration page in older Kubuntu versions. Was it removed? What's the proper way to change the GTK themes now?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what happened, but a first attempt to fix this was to go to `System Settings` | `Global Theme` and then changing the theme to Dark Breeze then back to Kubuntu.
However this solution didn't last long: after rebooting, the GTK2 theme was lost again.
Then I finally found out where the GTK2/3 theme settings have been moved (thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212082/531643)), that is under `System Settings` | `Application Style`, then `Configure GNOME/GTK Application Style ...` button: there, the GTK2 theme was set to blank (I don't know why), I set it to Breeze. This change fixed the problem for now, it even survived a reboot, I will monitor it to see whether it will last.